# Home directory, user database and key-based authentication

Tags: nfs, zfs, ssh-keys, home-directory, zpool

I want to share it NFS share with my users just like the home-directories (traditional way), but I don't want to create the users instead I want to get the server integrated with the github or google or opnsense's VPN users database and want to have the home-directory get created for the users, for authentication I am thinking if getting the key-based authentication for mounting the home-directory is possible.

Does anyone have any suggestion/advice on whether this is achievable ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could think of would be to use Sambda and CIFS mount.
With NFS you could just share a directory with write access to the group of users and they could create the directories they need. Having home directory mounted via NFS might not be a good idea.

If you would still need to use NFS and userhomedirs, consider LDAP or AD(PBIS) integration with the system and make sure to have /home/domain/local mounted over NFS.

It really depends if you want users to have that NFS mount mounted onto their systems or you need them to go to some server where you have their homedir in NFS mount.